# Laravel custom validation rule with dynamic message

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have a request for adding a show with a custom validation method in it that checks whether a show already exists that clashes with the date and time. If the method fails I want to say which show it clashes with in the validation error message.

```
class ShowStoreRequest extends Request {

    public function rules()
    {
        Validator::extend('time_clash_check', function($attribute, $value, $parameters)
        {
            list($day, $month, $year) = explode('/', $value);
            $date = $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day;
            $start_time = $parameters[0];
            $end_time = $parameters[1];
            $show_id = $parameters[2];

            $query = Show::where('date', '=', $date)->where(function($q) use ($start_time, $end_time) {
                // show overlaps beginning of another show
                $q->orWhere(function($q) use ($start_time, $end_time) {
                    $q->where('start_time', '>=', $start_time)
                      ->where('start_time', '<=', $end_time)
                      ->where('end_time', '>=', $end_time);

                // show is in the middle of the another show
                })->orWhere(function($q) use ($start_time, $end_time) {
                    $q->where('start_time', '<=', $start_time)
                      ->where('end_time', '>=', $end_time);

                // show overlaps the end of the another show
                })->orWhere(function($q) use ($start_time, $end_time) {
                    $q->where('start_time', '<=', $start_time)
                      ->where('end_time', '>=', $start_time)
                      ->where('end_time', '<=', $end_time);

                // show completely overlaps another show
                })->orWhere(function($q) use ($start_time, $end_time) {
                    $q->where('start_time', '>=', $start_time)
                      ->where('end_time', '<=', $end_time);
                });
            });

            if(!is_null($show_id)) {
                $query->where('id', '!=', $show_id);
            }

            $existing_show = $query->first();

            if(is_null($existing_show)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });

        $rules = [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'show_code' => 'required|alpha_num|min:10|max:11',
            'url_slug' => ['required', 'max:255', 'regex:/^[a-z0-9-_]+$/'],
            'youtube_url' => 'url',
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'date' => ['regex:/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}/', 'time_clash_check:'.$this->start_time.','.$this->end_time.','.$this->route('id')],
            'start_time' => ['regex:/[0-9]{1,2}\:[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}/'],
            'end_time' => ['regex:/[0-9]{1,2}\:[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}/']
        ];
    }
}
```

So if `time_clash_check` fails I want to output the value of `$existing_show->name` in the error message to tell them which show it clashes with. How would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this into your request file:

```
class ShowStoreRequest extends Request {

    public $exists;

    public function rules()
    {
        Validator::extend('time_clash_check', function($attribute, $value, $parameters)
        {
            list($day, $month, $year) = explode('/', $value);
            $date = $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day;
            $start_time = $parameters[0];
            $end_time = $parameters[1];
            $show_id = $parameters[2];

            $query = Show::where('date', '=', $date)->where(function($q) use ($start_time, $end_time) {
                // show overlaps beginning of another show
                $q->orWhere(function($q) use ($start_time, $end_time) {
                    $q->where('start_time', '>=', $start_time)
                      ->where('start_time', '<=', $end_time)
                      ->where('end_time', '>=', $end_time);

                // show is in the middle of the another show
                })->orWhere(function($q) use ($start_time, $end_time) {
                    $q->where('start_time', '<=', $start_time)
                      ->where('end_time', '>=', $end_time);

                // show overlaps the end of the another show
                })->orWhere(function($q) use ($start_time, $end_time) {
                    $q->where('start_time', '<=', $start_time)
                      ->where('end_time', '>=', $start_time)
                      ->where('end_time', '<=', $end_time);

                // show completely overlaps another show
                })->orWhere(function($q) use ($start_time, $end_time) {
                    $q->where('start_time', '>=', $start_time)
                      ->where('end_time', '<=', $end_time);
                });
            });

            if(!is_null($show_id)) {
                $query->where('id', '!=', $show_id);
            }

            $existing_show = $query->first();

            if(is_null($existing_show)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                $this->exists = $existing_show->name;
                return false;
            }
        });

        $rules = [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'show_code' => 'required|alpha_num|min:10|max:11',
            'url_slug' => ['required', 'max:255', 'regex:/^[a-z0-9-_]+$/'],
            'youtube_url' => 'url',
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'date' => ['regex:/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}/', 'time_clash_check:'.$this->start_time.','.$this->end_time.','.$this->route('id')],
            'start_time' => ['regex:/[0-9]{1,2}\:[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}/'],
            'end_time' => ['regex:/[0-9]{1,2}\:[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}/']
        ];
    }
}

public function messages()
{
    return [
        'time_clash_check ' => $this->exists . ' has clashed'
    ];
}
```

**Edit:**

Okay, so, I worked out what the problem was. Here's the solution:

```
class ShowStoreRequest extends Request {

    public $exists;

    public function rules()
    {
        Validator::extend('time_clash_check', function($attribute, $value, $parameters)
        {
            list($day, $month, $year) = explode('/', $value);
            $date = $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day;
            $start_time = $parameters[0];
            $end_time = $parameters[1];
            $show_id = $parameters[2];

            $query = Show::where('date', '=', $date)->where(function($q) use ($start_time, $end_time) {
                // show overlaps beginning of another show
                $q->orWhere(function($q) use ($start_time, $end_time) {
                    $q->where('start_time', '>=', $start_time)
                      ->where('start_time', '<=', $end_time)
                      ->where('end_time', '>=', $end_time);

                // show is in the middle of the another show
                })->orWhere(function($q) use ($start_time, $end_time) {
                    $q->where('start_time', '<=', $start_time)
                      ->where('end_time', '>=', $end_time);

                // show overlaps the end of the another show
                })->orWhere(function($q) use ($start_time, $end_time) {
                    $q->where('start_time', '<=', $start_time)
                      ->where('end_time', '>=', $start_time)
                      ->where('end_time', '<=', $end_time);

                // show completely overlaps another show
                })->orWhere(function($q) use ($start_time, $end_time) {
                    $q->where('start_time', '>=', $start_time)
                      ->where('end_time', '<=', $end_time);
                });
            });

            if(!is_null($show_id)) {
                $query->where('id', '!=', $show_id);
            }

            $existing_show = $query->first();

            if(is_null($existing_show)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                $this->exists = $existing_show->name;
                return false;
            }
        });

        Validator::replacer('time_clash_check', function($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters) {
            return str_replace(':variable', $this->exists, $message);
        });    

        $rules = [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'show_code' => 'required|alpha_num|min:10|max:11',
            'url_slug' => ['required', 'max:255', 'regex:/^[a-z0-9-_]+$/'],
            'youtube_url' => 'url',
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'date' => ['regex:/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}/', 'time_clash_check:'.$this->start_time.','.$this->end_time.','.$this->route('id')],
            'start_time' => ['regex:/[0-9]{1,2}\:[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}/'],
            'end_time' => ['regex:/[0-9]{1,2}\:[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}/']
        ];
    }
}

public function messages()
{
    return [
        'time_clash_check ' => ':variable has clashed'
    ];
}
```

That should fix the problem.

Comment: That would output the name of the show I'm creating. I want to output the name of the existing show that it clashes with.

Comment: Sorry, I miss-understood. Updated my post. I set the $this->exists as $existing_show->name, but you'll need to correct the value if "name" is wrong. I was guessing.

Comment: I tried that approach before posting the question but I think the messages method gets run before the validation rule so the exists property doesn't exist at that point.

Comment: Hmm, what version are you using? Just tested it and it's working.

Comment: @geoffs3310 I've updated my post again. I've used a replacer, and it fixes the issue.

Comment: 5.1 I'll try again if its working for you I must have done something wrong

Comment: Amazing thanks I've never heard of replacers before I'll try it out

Comment: I updated the post again just now, I was calling the wrong rule on the replacer. I was using my test rule. It should be: Validator::replacer('time_clash_check' - let me know if it works for you!

Comment: Certainly did! Thanks so much :-) :-) :-)